# Using RGB values in TKinter? EG. 255, 0, 0

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, colors, tkinter-canvas

Heyo! So, I've been working on this project, but I need some help. I'd like to be able to use the RGB values in tinker, for example:

```
color = askcolor()
canvas.create_oval(x0, y0, x0 + d, y0 + d, fill = color)
```

but when I do that, I get the following error:

```
tkinter.TclError: unknown color name "{254.9921875 67.26171875 67.26171875} #fe4343"
```

Is there any way I could either change that value to the nearest TKinter color or use that value in TKinter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51591456/can-i-use-rgb-in-tkinter#51592104

Answer (score 2):

askcolor return a tuple of two values. The first one is an RGB tuple of the chosen color. The second one is a hexadecimal string of the chosen color.

Try to use :

```
fill = color[1]
```

[tkinter color dialogs documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-color-dialogs.htm)

By the way, the error message shows the two values returned.